# Do browsers support HTML row selection

Tags: javascript, html

I have defined the following table:

```
<table id=scheduledTable class="table table-fixed">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
    
                        <th style="width:20%">Date</th>
                        <th style="width:20%">Duty</th>
                        <th style="width:20%"></th>
    
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody *ngIf="schedules">
                    <tr *ngFor="let s of schedules ; let i = index" (click)="ClickedRow(i)" [class.active]="i == HighlightRow">
                        <td>{{getDisplayDate(s.date)}} </td>
    
                        <td>{{s.userFunction}} </td>
                        <td style="white-space: nowrap" *ngIf="isLoggedAsAdmin">
                            <button type="button" (click)="onDeleteSchedule(s.id)"
                                class="btn btn-sm btn-danger btn-delete-account">
                                <span *ngIf="s.deleting" class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm mr-1"></span> Delete
                            </button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

I am wandering if there is native support in todays browsers for the row selection (e.g. ctrl-click - select and second ctrl-click unselects).
Any help appreciated.

Comment: HTML tables only define a tables layout, you can add whatever you like with JS, but the built in tables are static, non-interactive elements.

Comment: If it's a regular table. Firefox has the option to mark table cells with CTRL+click on individual `td` elements. Browsers like Chrome and Edge don't have this functionality. Unsure about Safari.

Comment: Does angular have any library to support something like that?

Comment: There is no native support for that (yet?), what you may be having to look for is a library that handles multi select on table rows or write your own module for it.

Comment: There might be such a library, but asking for recommendations here is off-topic, see the [help/on-topic]

Comment: _"Firefox has the option to mark table cells with CTRL+click on individual td elements."_ - I see a light-blue border/outline appearing - but I can't tell what actual _functionality_ this is supposed to provide. What exactly do _you_ mean, when you say "mark"? Or "select"? Mark/select for what _purpose_?

Comment: @Cbroe I use that functionality to copy table content to clipboard. If you hold down CTRL key and you  click with the mouse any cell it selects it and if you drag the selection it takes the whole range. But yet it's just for copying table content. There are extensions both for firefox and chrome that extend that behaviour

Answer (score 0):

By default, HTML tables are static and do not have any built-in interactivity. They are simply used to display tabular data in a structured way.

However, it is possible to make HTML tables interactive by adding interactivity using JavaScript and CSS.

Using JS, it can be done by adding event listeners and implementing functions to handle user interactions, such as clicking on a table row or cell.

Or can done by adding `tabindex` attribute to each `tr` element in the table, and use CSS to visually indicate when they are selected or hovered over.

---

Examples for both JS and CSS approach can be found in this snippet:

```js
function addRowHandlers() {
    var table = document.getElementById("tableId");
    var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var currentRow = table.rows[i];
        var createClickHandler = 
            function(row) 
            {
                return function() { 
                                        var cell = row.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
                                        var id = cell.innerHTML;
                                        alert("clicked on:" + id);
                                 };
            };

        currentRow.onclick = createClickHandler(currentRow);
    }
}
window.onload = addRowHandlers();
```

```css
table tr:focus{ outline: red solid 2px}
```

```html
<div>
    <table id="tableId" border=1>
      <tbody>
        <tr tabindex="0"><td>Table row 1</td></tr>
        <tr tabindex="0"><td>Table row 2</td></tr>
        <tr tabindex="0"><td>Table row 3</td></tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: An example snippet would be helpful :-)

Comment: Sure! have updated the answer with examples @node_modules

Comment: "However, it is possible to make HTML tables interactive by adding interactivity using JavaScript and CSS." — That is already noted in the question. It even has an example: `<tr *ngFor="let s of schedules ; let i = index" (click)="ClickedRow(i)" [class.active]="i == HighlightRow">`

Comment: I think I'd rather go for third party library. Thanks everybody for help.